# Cuantos numeros diferentes hay en un vector

Tags: c++, c

tengo una duda acerca de un ejercicio que pensé ayer. Mi duda era si se podía contar la cantidad de números diferentes(o son distintos) en un vector. Por ejemplo si un vector es v[4]={0,2,3,2}, aquí habría 3 números diferentes(0,3,2).En el código hay un total de 5 números distintos, sin embargo me devuelve 6 en vez de 5. No se donde está el fallo,espero que lo solucionen.Les dejo aquí el código que he realizado.Un saludo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int v[6]{3,1,8,2,7,2};
   int n=6;
   int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(v[i]!=v[i+1]){
            count++;
        }
    }

   cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
```

Comment: Tu código solo funciona si el array está ordenado. Además, lee fuera del array (*v[5+1]*) lo que es *undefined behavior* y puede hacer que el programa dé cualquier resultado o que falle su ejecución.

Comment: Aun con el vector ordenado, desborda en el último número en ese for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no estas contando los valores distintos; estas contando los valores que no son igual al siguiente valor:

```
if ( v[i] != v[i+1] ){
   count++;
```

Para ver si un valor es unico, usaremos un segundo arreglo, `r`, donde iremos colocando los valores únicos encontrados hasta el momento.

Por cada valor del arreglo original `v`, lo buscaremos en `r`. Si no está, lo agregamos a `r` y contamos un valor único más.

```
int r[8];
int unicos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    // Buscar v[i] dentro de la lista de valores unicos encontrados.
    for (j = 0; j < unicos; j++) {
        if (v[i] == r[j]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (j == unicos) {
        // No se encontro el valor, agregarlo a la lista de unicos.
        r[unicos++] = v[i];                                
    }
}

printf("%d", unicos);
```

**Demostración**

Hice un ejemplo un poco más exigente. Con estos valores

```
int v[8] = {3, 1, 8, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2};
int n = 8;
```

El resultado es cinco.

Answer (score 1):

Primero veamos

```
if(v[i]!=v[i+1]){
    count++;
}
```

Esto no funcionaría en todos los casos, solo con arrays ordenados. Por ejemplo, el caso `{3,5,2,3,5,2}`. Donde 3 es diferente a 5, pero luego se repite en la posición 3 del array.

> Sin embargo, me devuelve 6 en vez de 5.

Cuando en la iteración, `v[i]` sea igual al último elemento del array, `v[i + 1]` será un elemento que no pertenece al array. Dicho valor al no pertenecer al array, se deconoce su valor. Por lo tanto en la última iteración se estaría comparando con un valor probablemente también distinto, un valor basura.

Puedes hacer el experimento, haciéndole `std::cout` a un elemento fuera del rango de un array.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

*En mi caso, muestra `1 2 3 4 5 0 4199101 0 3 5`*

> Mi duda era si se podía contar la cantidad de números diferentes(o son distintos) en un vector.

**Sí.**

Habrán otras maneras, pero la que yo considero más conveniente es:

- Convertir el array en un [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)
- Obtener la cantidad de elementos en el set.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int a[] = {7,8,15,2,3,7,15}; 
    std::set<int> b{std::begin(a),std::end(a)};

    std::cout << b.size() << std::endl;
}
```

*Esto mostraría `5`*

Espero te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya tienes 2 muy buenas respuestas, aporto una solución usando la plantilla [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Básicamente vamos a iterar el `array` desde la posición 1 hasta el final, y determinaremos si el elemento que estamos iterando se encuentra en alguna posición anterior. Para ello utilizaremos la plantilla `find` a la que le indicaremos el rango que vamos a usar del `array` para la búsqueda.

Si el índice obtenido es diferente del valor final del rango, significa que el elemento ha sido encontrado en el `array` por lo tanto está repetido. Si el índice es igual al valor final del rango, entonces el elemento no ha sido encontrado y podemos aumentar el contador.

El ejemplo sería:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int arr[] = {7,8,15,2,3,7,15};
  int cantDiferentes = 0;
  int arrLength = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  cout << "Cantidad de elementos: " << arrLength << endl;
  if(arrLength > 0)
  {
    cantDiferentes++;
  }
  for(int i = 1; i < arrLength; ++i)
  {
    int current = arr[i];
    int * index;
    index = find(arr, arr + i, current);
    if(index == arr + i)
    {
      cantDiferentes++;
    }
  }
  cout << "Cantidad de elementos diferentes: " << cantDiferentes << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Espero que esto aporte otro enfoque para solucionar el problema.